# A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json

I tried this code in my controller :

```
List<ProductListingModels> prom = new List<ProductListingModels>();

prom.Add(new ProductListingModels()
{
    ID = item.ID,
    Name = item.Name,
    DepartmentID = item.DepartmentID.Value,
    BrandID = item.BrandID.Value
});

jr.Data = prom;
jr.JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet;
return Json(new
{
    ja = jr.Data,
}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

This is my ProductListingModel :

```
 public class ProductListingModels:ItemEntityDataContext
 {
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int DepartmentID { get; set; }
   public int BrandID { get; set; }
 }
```

It was an error :

> A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type.

But if I change from adding the object "prom" to adding something like string or integer, It works well. I don't know what problem happen of how to adding my objects.

Can any one show me the solution. Welcome to all your question and answer, Thanks so much.

Comment: right; we're serializing `jr.Data`, which is `prom`, which is a `List<ProductListingModels>` with a single item, consisting of `Id`, `Name`, `DepartmentID` and `BrandID` - can we please see `ProductListingModels` so we can see what the types are here, and what else it defines?

Comment: does it have any particular base-class? or any other fields/properties?

Comment: basically, locally I can repro it working fine, i.e. `"{\"ja\":[{\"ID\":123,\"Name\":\"abc\",\"DepartmentID\":456,\"BrandID\":789}]}"`

Comment: I still see no problem. Is this really full content of ProductListingModel class? Does the ProductListingModel inherit from another class?

Comment: Thanks to all your answer, and I added the inheriting of the ProductListingModel class ready.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I suspect the problem is with references ItemEntityDataContext superclass might hold to other objects. It is always a good idea to copy your data to a viewmodel class for passing into views. In your case however just use LINQ to select fields into new anonymous type and serialize with json. Something like this:

```
jr.Data = prom.Select(p => new 
{ 
    ID = p.ID, 
    Name = p.Name, 
    DepartmentID = p.DepartmentID,
    BrandID = p.BrandID
}).ToArray();
```

Comment: My culprit was Xelement in the dataclass